# How to subset data to achieve desired data mix?

Tags: r, random

Is there any R function that selects random subset of a data to have a desired mix?

For example I have 100 rows of 1, 2, 3 and 4's with 25% in each group. but instead I want the mix to be for example 20%, 20%, 35%, 25% by randomly selecting ideally maximum number of the 100 rows to achieve this.

I have tried to manually cut volume of groups with higher than wanted proportion (1's and 2's) but this is not efficient.

Is there a simpler way to do so?

An extension of this question is:
Suppose I have two columns A & B ans 100 rows. A has values 1 - 4 with 25% each, B has c("a", "b", "c") with 33% each. How do I randomly subset to have 1-4 with proportion of 20%, 20%, 35%, 25% respectively and (a, b, c) with proportion of 20%, 30%, 50%?

```
A  B
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  a
1  b
2  c
3  a
4  b
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for your first question. We can use functions from `dplyr` and `purrr` to achieve this.

```
set.seed(1)

# Create example data frame
dat <- data.frame(A = rep(1:4, times = 25),
                  B = c(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), times = 33), "a"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_split(A) %>%
  map2_dfr(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.35, 0.25), ~sample_frac(.x, .y))

dat2
# # A tibble: 25 x 2
#       A B    
#   <int> <chr>
#  1     1 a    
#  2     1 a    
#  3     1 a    
#  4     1 a    
#  5     1 b    
#  6     2 c    
#  7     2 c    
#  8     2 c    
#  9     2 a    
# 10     2 b    
# # ... with 15 more rows
```

This is for your question 2. We need to calculate the joint probability for each combination. After that, we can apply the similar code as for the question 1 for this.

```
set.seed(1)

# Create a larger data frame for demonstration 
dat3 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(100, dat, simplify = FALSE))

# Calculate the joint probability
p1 <- c("1" = 0.2, "2" = 0.2, "3" = 0.35, "4" = 0.25)
p2 <- c("a" = 0.2, "b" = 0.3, "c" = 0.5)

p <- as.vector(t(outer(p1, p2)))

dat4 <- dat3 %>%
  group_split(A, B) %>%
  map2_dfr(p, ~sample_frac(.x, .y))

# Verify the results

dat4 %>%
  count(A) %>%
  mutate(P = n/nrow(dat4))
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#       A     n     P
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1   164 0.197
# 2     2   166 0.199
# 3     3   298 0.358
# 4     4   205 0.246

dat4 %>%
  count(B) %>%
  mutate(P = n/nrow(dat4))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   B         n     P
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>
# 1 a       169 0.203
# 2 b       246 0.295
# 3 c       418 0.502
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but it reduces the data size quite a lot. Is there a way by reducing minimum amount of the data?